# Double For loops in R

Tags: r, loops

How do you properly write a double `for` loop in R?

For example, in C I would do

```
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    for (j=i; j <= 3; j++) {
        printf("%i,%i\n",i,j);
    }
    // Do more operations for i > 3...
}
```

which would generate the (artificial) sequence:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,2
2,3
3,3
```

In R you do not get the same behaviour when you write

```
for (i in 1:6) {
    for (j in i:3) {
        print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
    }
}
```

so I've been reduced to doing something like

```
for (i in 1:6) {
    j <- i
    while (j <= 3) {
        print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
        j <- j+1
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

As Shane mentioned, maybe I should make this clear: I am particularly interested in the code-style matching the mathematics to make it easier for students to understand. It seems that students are the most comfortable with `for` loops.

In particular, I want my students to simulate a [LIBOR market model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIBOR_market_model). The dynamics of the forward rate are to be simulated under the same probability measure. As such, for each time step and each 
 forward rate, the appropriate drift correction \mu_i needs to be calculated and added.

Comment: You mean i in 1:(2*N). Otherwise your i index will take only values N and 2*N.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've taken values now to make it clearer.

Comment: You might be able to make your goal a little clearer: are you trying to teach R to students who know C (for instance)?  There are probably many efficient ways to generate that sequence, but it looks like you're specifically interested in for() loops...

Comment: I'm teaching a course to MSc students in Financial Mathematics. They come from mixed backgrounds and most have never programmed before. I wish they all knew C, or even some other language well... :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry for asking what is potentially a dumb question, but in what sense can R not do this?  This works perfectly fine for me:

```
N <- 5
for (i in 0:(2*N)) {
   for (j in i:N) {
        print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
    }
}
```

Could it be that you just didn't put parentheses around the end of your sequence?

*Edit:*  I see...you want to enforce that the sequence i:3 is always <= 3?  I don't think that's possible with either a sequence or within the clause of a for statement.  You can set a break within the loop, but that's no better than your current approach:

```
for (i in 1:6) {
    for (j in i:3) {
        if(j > 3) break()
        print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
    }
}
```

Here's another way to generate this sequence without a for loop:

```
x <- cbind(rep(c(1,2,3), 3),
    rep(c(1,2,3), each=3))
```

Or with expand.grid (as per Dirk's suggestion):

```
x <- expand.grid(x=1:3, y=1:3)
```

Then remove the unwanted cases:

```
x[x[,1] >= x[,2],]
```

*Edit 2:* This may not suit your needs, but I believe that Quantlib has a Libor Market Model implementation.  I'm not sure if it's [exposed in RQuantlib](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rquantlib.html).

Comment: I've edited my question to hopefully make it clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: Using a "break" is nice, it means I don't need to explain "while". Thanks.

Comment: `break` doesn't need parentheses `()`.

Answer (score 10):

You can of course nest loops:

```
R> for (i in 1:3) for (j in 1:3) cat(i,j,i*j, "\n")
1 1 1 
1 2 2 
1 3 3 
2 1 2 
2 2 4 
2 3 6 
3 1 3 
3 2 6 
3 3 9 
R>
```

There is general sense that you *should not* as vectorised calls can be easier to read and write:

```
R> outer(1:3,1:3, "*")
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
R>
```

but if it is easier to develop with nexted loops, then do so.

As for the 'second index dependent on first index' issue you can use lower.tri(), upper.tri() or indexing to achieve that too.

```
R> X <- expand.grid(x=1:3, y=1:3)
R> X <- X[ X$x >= X$y, ]
R> outer(X$x, X$y, "*")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
[2,]    2    2    2    4    4    6
[3,]    3    3    3    6    6    9
[4,]    2    2    2    4    4    6
[5,]    3    3    3    6    6    9
[6,]    3    3    3    6    6    9
R>
```

Comment: Thanks, using outer is probably a good way to do it, I will give it a go. Though it makes the algorithm no longer looks like the math, so it makes it hard for my students to understand.

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that `i:3` is meaningful when `i>3`. For example, `5:3` gives `(5,4,3)`. All you need is a simple if statement to prevent the second loop being run when `i>3`.

```
for (i in 1:6) {
    if(i < 4) {
        for (j in i:3) {
            print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
        }
    }
    # Do more operations for i > 3...
}
```

However, if possible try to avoid the explicit looping. Dirk's and Shane's answers provide some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: This is nice, it means I don't need to explain what "while" does.